# High cpu usage for javaapplication

Tags: java

My java application's cpu usage is more(sometimes 80-100%). My application uses http data transfer in it.I checked cpu usage using jConsole. From that I realized that some thread pools use more time of cpu. I dont know how to find the threads in that pools. Somebody please help me to find the threads that cause more cpu usage..

Comment: How exactly can we help you find a problem with your application if you do not post relevant code?

Comment: You must put more effort into a question - this is like 'please do my homework'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use VisualVM instead of JConsole to monitor your application. I'm not sure but VisualVM's thread analyzer should me more feature-rich.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is still the case but VisualVm comes included with the JDK, it was included with the 1.6.0_10 version that I've got installed.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a fully-fledged profiler such as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) (you can download a free evaluation version from their Web site). It will tell you exactly which threads are taking up the CPU, and what exactly they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

A profiling tool such as [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html) should help you find hot spots in your application.

However, why do you think that using a lot of CPU is a bad thing? If there's work to be done then you want to get it done, so you'll use CPU. If you have a multi-threaded application, some threads doing processing others reading stuff from the network then high CPU usage may be exactly what should happen - for example if there's lots of analysis of the retrieved data.

Comment: @aix, I downloaded the yourkit but that is for java6. My application is running in java5.till now I used jconsole to monitor the memory etc. It didn't give any information about threads which uses more cpu time. Do you know any profiler for java5 and gives the cpu usage information???

Answer (score 0):

Using the topthreads plugin in JConsole will quickly reveal what the busy threads are busy with... Start it with

```
jconsole -pluginpath topthreads.jar
```

You can download the topthreads jar file here: http://lsd.luminis.eu/new_version_topthreads_jconsole_plugin/